# Как получить канал по id в discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Мне надо получить объект канала по его ID. Как это сделать?

Comment: Ну, начнем с того, что канал это часть сервера, что вам тоже нужно найти. Ну а дальше просто Клиент -> ПолучитьGuild(id_сервера) -> У объекта сервера ПолучитьКанал(id_канала). Методы думаю без проблем найдете сами. Некоторые библиотеки имеют сразу метод по типу GetChannel, который сразу дает нужное.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите получить канал по его id при использовании команды, то можно воспользоваться методом `get_channel()` из класса `Guild`

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot()

@bot.command()
async def channel(ctx: commands.Context):
    channel_id = 1234567890
    channel = ctx.guild.get_channel(channel_id)
```

Также, канал можно получить через функцию `get` из модуля `utils`. (P.S. Пример ниже ищет канал среди всех каналов серверов к которым бот подключён.)

```
import discord

from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot()

channel_id = 1234567890
channel = discord.utils.get(bot.get_all_channels, id=channel_id)
```